# How to iterate array keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I have an array created with this code:

```
var widthRange = new Array();
widthRange[46] = { min:0,  max:52 };
widthRange[66] = { min:52, max:70 };
widthRange[90] = { min:70, max:94 };
```

I want to get each of the values 46, 66, 90 in a loop. I tried `for (var key in widthRange)` but this gives me a whole bunch of extra properties (I assume they are functions on the object). I can't use a regular for loop since the values are not sequential.

Comment: It looks like you have data which, while it happens to have numeric keys, isn't actually array data. I'd look at using a regular object here.

Comment: @Quentin It's called a sparse array. Performance-wise, it's best to use an array instead of an object here. Also, performance-wise, the best answer is not even listed: `Array.prototype.forEach`. Calling `Object.keys` on an array is illperformant because browsers don't optimize for it. `for(var key in array)` is bad because it traverses the prototype and stringifies each number key it encounters (converting doubles to base10 is very slow). `forEach`, however, was designed exactly for the purpose of iterating sparse arrays and will give your code excellent performance compared to other solutions

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to call the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function to check whether the property is actually defined on the object itself (as opposed to its prototype), like this:

```
for (var key in widthRange) {
    if (key === 'length' || !widthRange.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    var value = widthRange[key];
}
```

Note that you need a separate check for `length`.
However, you shouldn't be using an array here at all; you should use a regular object.  All Javascript objects function as associative arrays.

For example:

```
var widthRange = { };  //Or new Object()
widthRange[46] = { sel:46, min:0,  max:52 };
widthRange[66] = { sel:66, min:52, max:70 };
widthRange[90] = { sel:90, min:70, max:94 };
```

Comment: Really?  Wow I learn something every day here, and so often it's from you SLaks :-)  I am surprised that Array keeps track of its explicitly-set indexes like that. Maybe I shouldn't be.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks, changing it to an object seems the nicest solution. One more question: is there a way to iterate in reverse order?

Comment: No; you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: Why do you need a separate check for `length`? Isn't is marked as `[[DontEnum]]` in all browsers?

Comment: @Roatin: I don't know.  Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 85):

The stringified keys can be queried with [`Object.keys(array)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: This returns the keys as strings, not numbers, just so everyone is aware.

Comment: The best solution... TY

Comment: Made my day! :D <3
This solved it where `array.keys()` returned nothing.

Comment: This is the solution

Answer (score 18):

If you are doing any kind of array/collection manipulation or inspection I highly recommend using [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/). It's small, well-tested and will save you days/weeks/years of javascript headache. Here is its keys function:

**Keys**

*Retrieve all the names of the object's properties.*

```
_.keys({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3});
=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Say your array looked like
`arr = [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }, { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 } ]` (or possibly other keys) you could do

```
arr.map((o) => {
    return Object.keys(o)
}).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev.concat(curr)
}).filter((col, i, array) => {
    return array.indexOf(col) === i
});
```

`["a", "b", "c"]`

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var i = 0; i < widthRange.length; ++i) {
  if (widthRange[i] != null) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

<strike>You can't really get just the keys you've set because that's not how an Array works. Once you set element 46, you also have 0 through 45 set too (though they're null).</strike>

You could always have *two* arrays:

```
var widthRange = [], widths = [], newVal = function(n) {
  widths.push(n);
  return n;
};
widthRange[newVal(26)] = { whatever: "hello there" };

for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; ++i) {
  doSomething(widthRange[widths[i]]);
}
```

**edit** well it may be that I'm all wet here ...

Comment: Arrays only keep track of length, they don't go through and create however many objects. Basically, when a new index is found it checks to see if that new index is greater than length...if it is that new index becomes the new length. Because of that it is possible to get only the indexes you defined with a for-in loop

Answer (score 2):

```
widthRange.map(function(_, i) { return i });
```

or

```
widthRange.map((_, i) => i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original example works just fine for me:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var widthRange = new Array();
widthRange[46] = { sel:46, min:0,  max:52 };
widthRange[66] = { sel:66, min:52, max:70 };
widthRange[90] = { sel:90, min:70, max:94 };

var i = 1;
for (var key in widthRange)
{
    document.write("Key #" + i + " = " + key + "; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; min/max = " + widthRange[key].min + "/" + widthRange[key].max + "<br />");
    i++;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Results in the browser (Firefox 3.6.2 on Windows XP):

```
Key #1 = 46;     min/max = 0/52
Key #2 = 66;     min/max = 52/70
Key #3 = 90;     min/max = 70/94
```

Comment: I bet he's importing Prototype or something like that.  In general, those "in" loops are risky.

Comment: Well I'm using jQuery but also Joomla which uses mootools, something is adding those properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an Object (`{}`) and not an array (`[]`) for this.

A set of data is associated with each key. It screams for using an object. Do:

```
var obj = {};
obj[46] = { sel:46, min:0,  max:52 };
obj[666] = { whatever:true };

// This is what for..in is for
for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(obj[prop]);
}
```

Maybe some utility stuff like this can help:

```
window.WidthRange = (function () {
  var obj = {};
  return {
    getObj: function () {return obj;}
    , add: function (key, data) {
        obj[key] = data;
        return this; // enabling chaining
      }
  }
})();

// Usage (using chaining calls):
WidthRange.add(66, {foo: true})
.add(67, {bar: false})
.add(69, {baz: 'maybe', bork:'absolutely'});

var obj = WidthRange.getObj();
for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(obj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate an Array from an Array's keys, use

```js
Array.from(Array(10).keys());
```

The example above will give an array of 0 to 9. It is not exactly what you asked for but I hope this gives an insight into this method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work.

```
var widthRange = new Array();
widthRange[46] = { sel:46, min:0,  max:52 };
widthRange[66] = { sel:66, min:52, max:70 };
widthRange[90] = { sel:90, min:70, max:94 };

for (var key in widthRange)
{
    document.write(widthRange[key].sel + "<br />");
    document.write(widthRange[key].min + "<br />");
    document.write(widthRange[key].max + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function what works fine with every instance of Objects (Arrays are those).

```
Object.prototype.toArray = function()
{
    if(!this)
    {
      return null;
    }

    var c = [];

    for (var key in this) 
    {
        if ( ( this instanceof Array && this.constructor === Array && key === 'length' ) || !this.hasOwnProperty(key) ) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        c.push(this[key]);
    }

    return c;
};
```

Usage:

```
var a   = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
a[11]   = 4;
a["js"] = 5;

console.log(a.toArray());

var b = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, f: function() { return 4; }, five: 5 };
b[7] = 7;

console.log(b.toArray());
```

Output:

```
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
> [ 7, 1, 2, 3, function () { return 4; }, 5 ]
```

It may be useful for anyone.

Comment: Extending a prototype that you didn't create is a very bad idea, no matter how convenient you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

... ????

Alternatively, if you have a list of items you want to use...

```
var range = [46, 66, 90]
    , widthRange=[]
    , write=[];

    widthRange[46] = { min:0, max:52 }; 
    widthRange[66] = { min:52, max:70 }; 
    widthRange[90] = { min:70, max:94 }; 

for(var x=0; x<range.length; x++){var key, wr;

    key = range[x];

    wr = widthRange[key] || false;

    if(wr===false){continue;}

    write.push(['key: #',key, ', min: ', wr.min, 'max:', wr.max].join(''));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your input data:

```
let widthRange = new Array()
widthRange[46] = { min:0,  max:52 }
widthRange[61] = { min:52, max:70 }
widthRange[62] = { min:52, max:70 }
widthRange[63] = { min:52, max:70 }
widthRange[66] = { min:52, max:70 }
widthRange[90] = { min:70, max:94 }
```

Declarative approach:

```
const relevantKeys = [46,66,90]
const relevantValues = Object.keys(widthRange)
    .filter(index => relevantKeys.includes(parseInt(index)))
    .map(relevantIndex => widthRange[relevantIndex])
```

`Object.keys` to get the keys, using `parseInt` to cast them as numbers.
`filter` to get only ones you want.
`map` to build an array from the original object of just the indices you're after, since `Object.keys` loses the object values.

Debug:

```
console.log(widthRange)
console.log(relevantKeys)
console.log(relevantValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but nowadays you can use forEach, which is efficient  and will retain the keys as numbers:

```
let keys = widthRange.map((v,k) => k).filter(i=>i!==undefined))
```

This loops through widthRange and makes a new array with the value of the keys, and then filters out all sparce slots by only taking the values that are defined.

(Bad idea, but for thorughness: If slot 0 was always empty, that could be shortened to `filter(i=>i)` or `filter(Boolean)`

And, it may be less efficient, but the numbers can be cast with `let keys = Object.keys(array).map(i=>i*1)`