# Get list of all elements in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to obtain a list of all elements that are in a JavaScript array, but I've noticed that using `array.toString` does not always show all the contents of the array, even when some elements of the array have been initialized. Is there any way to print each element of an array in JavaScript, along with the corresponding coordinates for each element? I want to find a way to print a list of all coordinates that have been defined in the array, along with the corresponding values for each coordinate.

http://jsfiddle.net/GwgDN/3/

```
var coordinates = [];
coordinates[[0, 0, 3, 5]] = "Hello World";

coordinates[[0, 0, 3]] = "Hello World1";

console.log(coordinates[[0, 0, 3]]);
console.log(coordinates[[0, 0, 3, 5]]);
console.log(coordinates.toString()); //this doesn't print anything at all, despite the fact that some elements in this array are defined
```

Comment: Id advise you to use Firefox and download the Firebug addon. I used to have q's like this, till I got the addon.

Comment: Or use [Google Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), has great developer tools.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it's because the question would be easy to answer with a small amount of research and/or reading.  Sometimes it's tempting to downvote legitimate questions when it seems like the OP was stuck on something for 3 minutes before asking the question.

Comment: `despite the fact that some elements in this array are defined` Arrays only take in integer indexes: `[][0] = 1`, `[]["string"] = 1` won't work.

Comment: In your example, `[0, 0, 3, 5]` will turn into `0,0,3,5`, creating an Object: `{"0,0,3,5": "Hello World"}`. Since there is no item in your Array, `coordinates,toString()` will output `""`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509432/how-to-get-array-keys-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually when you use coordinates[[0, 0, 3]] then this means coordinates object with [0, 0, 3] as key. It will not push an element to array but append a property to the object. So use this line which loop through objects. [See this for other ways to loop through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members),

```
Object.keys(coordinates).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, coordinates[key]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GwgDN/17/

Comment: This is the first working solution that I've found. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use type 'object' instead 'array' for coordinates

```
var coordinates = {};
coordinates[[0, 0, 3, 5]] = "Hello World";

coordinates[[0, 0, 3]] = "Hello World1";

console.log(coordinates[[0, 0, 3]]);
console.log(coordinates[[0, 0, 3, 5]]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(coordinates));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eeHy/

Comment: I see in FF/Chrome:
`Hello World1
Hello World
{"0,0,3,5":"Hello World","0,0,3":"Hello World1"}`

Comment: This is a good workaround, but I still want to know how to print the defined coordinates of an array instead of an object.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - An array is an object.  See the answer by user960567

Comment: @jahroy I still don't understand why this only works when coordinates is initialized to `{}` instead of `new Array()`. It seems a bit surprising to me.

Comment: Definition from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array): The JavaScript Array global object is a constructor for arrays, which are high-level, list-like objects.
I think Array don't work fine in this case due to the fact that Array requires numeric keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i<coordinates.length;i++)
{
document.write(coordinates[i] + "<br >");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use join function to get all elements of array.use following code

```
for (var i in coordinates)
{
    if( typeof coordinates[i] == 'string' ){
        console.log( coordinates[i] + "<br >");
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem: `coordinates.join(",")` doesn't print anything in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/GwgDN/7/

Comment: Instead of printing the coordinates, it now prints a list of functions: http://jsfiddle.net/GwgDN/10/

Comment: do not use `for in` for iterating array values. use for(;;) or Array.forEach

Comment: Array.forEach is ok but for(;;) is not because we can iterate if array's index is numeric in some cases where key is "string" type then we can't use for(;;)

Answer (score 0):

Look at coordinates in the debugger and you will see that you have set the properties [0,0,3,5] and [0,0,3] of the **object** coordinates. That is although coordinates is an array you are not using it as an array.

Comment: What I really want to do is print the coordinates of each element in the array.