# get variable from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to get the key from the `JSON` Array?
This is my JSON Array

```
****JAVASCRIPT****
var employees = [
                 { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
                 { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
                 { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
               ];
```

From this JSON I need the result key. I mean  "firstName", "lastName",  not John, Anna, Peter 
Please help to get the keys from JSON.

Comment: there are 3 firstname and lastname there which one do you want

Comment: `employees[0].firstname` will return `John`, `employees[1].firstname` will return `Anna` and so on.

Comment: no. I want to have a solution "firstName", "lastName".
also. not John,Anna,Peter

Comment: He wants [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2509432/1267304).

Comment: @user2894088: state your question more clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/1072/**

```
var employees = '[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}]';

var myData = JSON.parse(employees);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(myData, function() {
        $('<li>' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + '</li>').appendTo("#groups");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving javascript in external file, save as filename.json

```
var employees = [
                 { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
                 { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
                 { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
               ];
```

Then improt filename.json in webpage using jquery as
//jquery plugin must be added first

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("filename.json",function(result){
alert(result[0].firstname + result[0].lastname);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var employees = [
             { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
             { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
             { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
           ]; //your array

for(var i in employees)
{
var fname=employees[i].firstName
var lname=employees[i].lastName
console.log(fname) //all first names
console.log(lname) //all last names
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8TB6Z/

Comment: no. I want to have a solution "firstName", "lastName".
also. not John,Anna,Peter

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `key`. `Object` has a prototype keys which returns an Array of keys in an Object

```
Object.keys(employees); // returns ["firstName", "lastName"]
```

Also

```
for(i in employees){
var key = i;
var val = employees[i];
for(j in val)
    {
    var sub_key = j;
    var sub_val = val.j;
    console.log(sub_key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var employees = [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
];
$.each(employees,function(f,n){                    
    $.each(n,function(ff,nn){
        console.log("field:"+ff+" value:"+nn);                        
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/9gSk3/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: but I see many times "firstName" and "lastName". How to show  only one time?

Comment: @user2894088 you see it 3 times because you have 3 objects. if you have same field names across your array `employees`, you can do it just 1 time. [See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9gSk3/1/)