# Check if index is defined?

Tags: arrays

Is there a warning that I am accessing an index that might not be defined?

[ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhmArgWwEYFMBOBtAXRgF4ZCBuAKDhgDJb48AmAgOihADEBLOLAEwAUASiA)

[Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlVMV.png)

I defined an empty array and I tried to access an item that is not defined for which I did not get an error and the project built

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate array keys in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509432/how-to-iterate-array-keys-in-javascript)